# Updated phone, now fingerprint & WiFi don't work and I can't read or write from internal storage

Tags: updates

OnePlus 5 128GB, running OOS 4.5.15, rooted with Magisk 15.1, tried updating to latest OTA (Oreo), ended up bricking the phone, unbricked it, restored Nougat + backups of /data and /sdcard, now everything works except WiFi (stays on "turning on..."), fingerprint sensor (only works as home button) and sdcard isn't readable (I can only list files, but when I try to read or write I get EACCES.

Tried flashing latest firmware+modem, didn't work.

Tried wiping system/data/storage and flashing Nougat again, in the "first setup" page it was able to list WiFi networks but couldn't connect (stayed on "saved, secure").

Now I reloaded all my backups so I have an almost working phone, but without internal storage I can't do much. I can't take pictures, can't download files, can't play games (obb is on internal storage).

It worked fine before the update so it can't be a hardware problem, and even, it would be surprising that both the WiFi antenna, the fingerprint sensor and the eMMC card stop working at the same time.

Also worth mentioning that I can write to internal storage without any problems from TWRP.

edit: oops, wrong site. I forgot there was an Android-specific board. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I figured out the solution for each problem:

- Wi-Fi: I needed to delete `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` (which had been restored from Nougat) and reboot
- Fingerprint: Delete `/data/system/users/0/fpdata` and `/data/system/users/0/settings_fingerprint.xml`
- Storage: Wipe storage from TWRP, reboot to OS to reformat it, and restore files from TWRP

For those who would be wondering how to update from OOS Nougat to Oreo, [here is a guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/how-to/guide-upgrade-4-5-15-rooted-encrypted-5-t3730891).